# What is a small object in Golang?

Tags: go

In some Golang Tips said that: small object should pass by value and big object should pass by reference.

But how big object is small object?

If a struct has 10+ Fields. should it pass by value?

Comment: That’s not really a very good tip. It’s better to use a pointer or value that fits the problem you’re trying to solve. As for size, 10 bool fields is still smaller than a single slice (on a 64 bit system), and anything smaller than a cache line or two is probably faster to copy than to dereference. Performance depends on a lot of things, and always needs to be measured first.

Comment: I would think that passing a struct by a pointer is always a good idea, no matter how many fields it has, over time it always can bigger.

Comment: But because of Golang GC. It's better to use ```[]SmallStruct``` than to use ```[]*SmallStruct```.

Comment: It depends. Sometimes you must use `[]*Struct`.

Comment: "But because of Golang GC. It's better to use" --- it's not. Performance optimisations do not scale: you must benchmark every case in isolation and make decisions based on the numbers and your particular case, not based on an advice from a stranger from the internet.

Comment: @AdrianWitas Your advice is a bad one.

Comment: @Volker It is just a small voice in the discussion. Can you please elaborate what's wrong with that, I am not saying to use a pointer for map or slice, When I started with go a few years ago, I was thinking way too much about  if for this or that struct shall I use pointers or not. Now I'm pretty much using it all over the places for structs,

Comment: @AdrianWitas Pointer methods never make a copy of the objects they are invoked on which might be nice from a performance perspective but sometimes working on a copy (by using a value method) produces a more usable API: You get a copy, the method can be invoked concurrently without data races and the original value is not modified under any circumstances (some tiny bit of const-ness here in Go). "Always" is almost always a bad advice anyway.

Comment: @Volker - What you say is correct, and as you say "Always" is dangerous. There are cases in which making a copy can be dangerous though if you don't know what's inside the strut, like if it has a mutex. I think good guidance is to use whatever an api gives you (if it has creation method that provides a pointer to a new instance then use it as a pointer) and design your own apis to create instances as you want them to be used.

Comment: @Volker - I'd also be a little careful to caveat that "little bit of constness" as a guard against race conditions. Although using a value receiver prevents modification of the struct itself, it doesn't prevent the calling of pointer methods on any struct members that are defined as pointers. Therefore underlying data structures can be modified and race conditions created.

Answer (score 2):

As you see from the discussion it is "hard" to understand when to use a pointer or a reference. If you are learning the Golang I suggest to use this approach to decide when to use pointer or reference:

**I need to use a struct only for read purpose**

In this case I suggest to use a pointer to a struct, that's for performance reason (copy a struct is a time consuming operation as you can tell, no matter if is a "big" struct or a small one).

**I need to use a struct on multiple function each one write something on the struct but the various function should be no influence each other**

In this case you should pass the struct as reference.

**I need to use a struct on multiple function each one write something on the struct and the various function should be use the result of previous function**

In this case you should pass the struct by pointer.

As you can see this approach avoids to think about the "dimension" of the struct and focus on the use of the struct, I think this is a better approach because is not always easy to define the dimension of a struct.

Comment: Thanks, [This](https://github.com/gopherchina/conference/blob/master/2018/1.1%20%E5%9F%BA%E4%BA%8EGo%E6%9E%84%E5%BB%BA%E6%BB%B4%E6%BB%B4%E6%A0%B8%E5%BF%83%E4%B8%9A%E5%8A%A1%E5%B9%B3%E5%8F%B0%E7%9A%84%E5%AE%9E%E8%B7%B5.pdf) suggest use ```map[int]SampleStruct``` replace the ```map[int]*SampleStruct```. A lots of SampleStruct objects will slow down the GC.I want to know what is a *SampleStruct* or how sample is a *SampleStruct*

Comment: I think SampleStruct in this case mean an example struct. The whole point of the example is instead store a struct in the map if you store the pointer of that struct the map you have a performance increment for memory read/write. That's because with a pointer reference you don't copy the whole struct each time you try to get the struct using the key.

Comment: It suggest use ```map[int]SampleStruct```, not use ```map[int]*SampleStruct```, think million of sample objects in ```map[int]*SampleStruct```, The GC will scan every object in the map. but the other will not. If the ```SampleStruct``` is big. It will cause an other question. that is pass-by-value will copy the whole struct like you say. I want to find the balance between of them.

Comment: I think in this case you can choose using other factor, there isn't any "always good" decision for this kind of problem